# How to get the last sheet created in excel?

Tags: excel

How to get the last sheet created in excel ?

I used GetSheets.Last, and it work but he found me the last sheet what it is in queued, it’s right, but if my last sheet doesn’t follow the order of the queued for example it is in the middle, the function GetSheets.Last doesn’t work.
Exist some function where the robot can found or understand which sheet has been created for last ?

Thank you very much

best regards

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the workbook, there is a `NewSheet` event that can help you get the sheet at the very moment it is created. The complete signature is `Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)`

Once you close/reopen the workbook, the information will be lost though, so you need to save the sheet's name in some cell for future use.
It can be:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = Sh.Name
End Sub
```